# Как выполнить ALTER DATABASE команду для БД созданной EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

У меня вылезает ошибка

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
 "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.Lines'.'PK_dbo.Lines'
 in database 'C:\USERS\DEZMONT\BIN\DEBUG\APPDATA\STRINGSDB.MDF'
 because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.
 Create disk space by deleting unneeded files,
 dropping objects in the filegroup,
 adding additional files to the filegroup,
 or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup."
```

Как я понял тут объясняется как исправить: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003578/entity-framework-set-autogrowth-and-maxsize

Но я слишком слаб в SQL и не могу понять какой именно скрипт мне необходимо выполнить в методе UP. Пожалуйста, напишите пример скрипта, который надо сунуть в Sql().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно такой, предполагая, что группа Primary в STRINGSDB состоит только из одного файла с логическим именем STRINGSDB:

```
ALTER DATABASE [STRINGSDB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = 'STRINGSDB', FILEGROWTH = 10%, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED )
```

Comment: А где и как я могу посмотреть имена базы и файла?
Имею ввиду "[STRINGSDB] и NAME = 'STRINGSDB'"

Comment: В обозревателе объектов SQL в Хранилище?

Comment: @АлександрЛи Вы чем с базой работаете? Management Studio? Или инструментами работы с БД в Visual Studio?

Comment: Наверное, инструментами VS.
Ну имя вроде как зашло. Теперь другая проблема.
Значение не может быть неопределенным.
Имя параметра: connection

Но для этого я пожалуй новый вопрос задам.